# Display CSS content above everything else

Tags: html, css, z-index

I found a very simple CSS example for creating custom tooltips with the `content` setting and the demo of it looked great. I took the styling and implemented it into my own page, however I quickly noticed that the tooltip seems to be using the min-width as the width and is being displayed below everything else.

I've tried dozens of variations and so far nothing has worked to resolve this. Can anyone provide insight into how this can be fixed?

[image]

```
span[data-tooltip]
{
    position: relative;
    cursor: help;
}
span[data-tooltip]:hover:after
{
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    right: -200%;
    background: rgba(240,240,240,1.0);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
    min-width: 10em;
    padding: 0.25em;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span data-tooltip='Tool Tip'><img src='http://www.economicmodeling.com/wp-content/uploads/Info-icon.jpg' width=12px height=12px></span>
```

Comment: Try `z-index` css property.

Comment: Why is this question tagged javascript and jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `z-index`:

```
span[data-tooltip]:hover:after
{
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    right: -200%;
    background: rgba(240,240,240,1.0);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
    min-width: 10em;
    padding: 0.25em;
    text-shadow: none;
    z-index:99;
}
```

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: I feel stupid at how simple it was, I even considered that but thought it was for images only for some reason. Thank you so much, I will accept your answer once the proper time passes.

Comment: @BrettPowell Haha, it happens to everyone :) z-index has to be positioned to be used though.